# CakePhp html link query

Tags: cakephp

I want a link opening in another browser tab and not the user is located.

```
<?=__('Development by ').$this->Html->link('Test','http://www.test.cl',array('class'=>'orange-link'));?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the target `_blank` that opens a new blank tab you want to open the link and the link arm use `$this->Html->link`

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use php short tags, they simply suck and can cause issues.

Learn some HTML basics: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

> The target attribute specifies where to open the linked document.

```
$this->Html->link('Lixsys','http://www.lixsys.cl',array(
    'class'=> 'orange-link'
    'target'=> '_blank'
));
```